# how to copy a file contents and add a user input in the correct order

Tags: python, list, file

I am trying to  to make a new file and copy the words from another file into the new one, ask the user for an input and insert the new word in the right place.

```
fo = open("search.text".'r')
item = fo.readlines()
print(item)
fo.close()
newitem = int("please enter a word")
item.append(newitem)
mynewitem = sorted(item)
print(mynewitem)
with open("file2.txt", "w") as output:
    output.write(mynewitem)
```

Comment: What is your question? What is *the right place*?

Answer (score 0):

The `search.txt` file have the following contents:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
```

By giving that, here is my code:

```
new_item = raw_input("please enter a word: ")     # entry 10 as example
with open("search.txt", "r") as fp:
  items = [item.strip() for item in fp.readlines()]
items.append(new_item)
output = "\n".join(items)
with open("result.txt", "w") as fp:
  fp.write(output)
```

In the `result.txt` file, you will have:

```
1
2
3
4
5
7
8
10
```

Hope it helps.